# Give sheet name to CSV file when generated from Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working on jasper reports 6.0.4. I want to generate a report in CSV format. How to give sheet name to CSV file? For Excel, there were properties to set sheet name but there were no properties for CSV. Is there any property to set sheet name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values
it's a text format, it has no sheet name. So I think you can't do it. You can open CSV in excel or other program, but it still will be just comma separated plain text. It can't have multiple sheets and sheet name.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is a generic problem. If we open CSV file in Excel, Excel will take CSV file name as sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such property to rename the sheet if we open CSV file in Excel. Excel will just parse comma separated values and put them in Sheet1 and gives sheet name as file name.